# When I hit ./iiq console in command prompt my Sailpoint says database version doesn't match the system version

Tags: sailpoint

I'm trying to run the training modules in sailpoint, where I was following the exercises. I was able to set up the database and all. When I try to run the Identityiq console, using ./iiq console, it flashes the error, the database version and the system version do not match. How do I change the versions to make them match?

I tried changing the schema version to the system version, but it doesn't match as it was checking database version and system version.

in the bin directory, i used the command
$./iiq console

This was the result: System version 6.1-64 doesn't match database version 6.2-32 [Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikn7K.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run command : iiq patch 6.2

Answer (score 2):

There are two options here

1. Either install the patch for 6.2
2. Drop the database and run the database scripts from the web-inf/database folder.